# Convert char* array to TCHAR array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I've seen a bunch of answers on how to convert a char array to a TCHAR array in C++, but none for pure C.

Here's what I've tried:

```
const TCHAR* ptr = NULL;
TCHAR newPath[100];
ptr = _tcsrchr(dllPath, _T('.'));
_tcsncpy(newPath, dllPath, ptr - dllPath + 1);
newPath[ptr - dllPath + 1] = NULL;
```

Crashes. Here's another thing, except A2T doesn't seem to be available in just C (not c++)

```
TCHAR* newPath = A2T(dllPath);
```

So, how can I convert a char array to a TCHAR array in just C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TCHAR *tstrTo;
int tstrLen;
#ifdef UNICODE
tstrLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, dllPath, strlen(dllPath), NULL, 0);
tstrTo = (TCHAR*) malloc(tstrLen * sizeof(TCHAR));
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, dllPath, strlen(dllPath), tstrTo, tstrLen);
#else
tstrTo = strdup(dllPath);
tstrLen = strlen(tstrTo);
#endif
// use tstrTo up to tstrLen characters as needed...
free(tstrTo);
```

Comment: This code converts to TCHAR*. How can we convert to TCHAR[]?

Comment: @Halil `TCHAR[]` is fixed length at compile time. You would simply get rid of `malloc()` and `strdup()`, eg: `TCHAR tstrTo[MAX_PATH]; int tstrLen; #ifdef UNICODE tstrLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, dllPath, strlen(dllPath), tstrTo, MAX_PATH); #else tstrLen = min(strlen(dllPath), MAX_PATH); memcpy(tstrTo, dllPath, tstrLen); #endif`

Answer (score 0):

... for the second time in the last 24 hours I've found the solution to my own question in minutes.

This works:

```
int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &dllPath[0], (int)strlen(dllPath), NULL, 0);
TCHAR wstrTo[MAX_PATH];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &dllPath[0], (int)strlen(dllPath), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
```

Comment: Use `size_needed` to dynamically allocate `wstrTo` using `malloc()` or `LocalAlloc()`, otherwise you risk a buffer overflow if `size_needed` is more than `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: This will not work if _UNICODE is not defined. TCHAR is the same as wchar_t if _UNICODE is defined, otherwise just char. (And if your app is not intended to compile without _UNICODE, then IMO that is missing the point of using TCHAR at all)

Comment: There's also a possible buffer overflow here. What happens if size_needed > MAX_PATH?

Comment: Didn't read Remy's comment saying the same thing before I posted mine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you give an example?

Comment: You can use A2T, one of the TCHAR conversion macros, for this, but remember they use local automatic variable space and therefore should be avoided if you have large data elements that need conversion *or* you're looping over many items. In that case you could code your own based on a preprocessor. In either case honestly there is *zero* reason to do *any* of this. The usefulness of `TCHAR` - *anything* ran out as soon as Windows Me found its proper place, a burial ground, and there is *no* good reason to use them anymore (that I can think of anyway). `char` to `wchar_t` is useful; thats it.

Comment: @ChristianStewart Good question. There was, before the ATL influx, a version that did. I highly doubt it now that there is so much incest between ATL and all-things-utility to Microsoft's windows API. The source is simple enough to convert if you absolutely had to have it though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be stable - I keep getting random characters sometimes... What's a good way to do this??

Comment: @ChristianStewart: I posted an answer with an example.